# Spring MVC form button submit not calling API in controller

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc, controller

I was having some problem with Spring MVC. I have two buttons in a form, each button will call different API. My JSP:

```
<form:form action="aSearch.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="aTO">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="submit"
                name="doiSearchList"
                value="Left search" />
            </td>

            <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
                name="docSearchList"
                value="Right search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Then, in my Controller, I have these API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aSearch.do", params = "docSearchList", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String docSearchList(Model model, @ModelAttribute("aTO") @Valid ATO aSearchForm,
        @SessionAttribute(Constants.USERSESSION) UserAccountTO userAccountTO,
        BindingResult bindingResult, 
        HttpServletRequest request) {
      // business logic
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/aSearch.do", params ="doiSearchList", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String doiSearchList(Model model, @ModelAttribute("TO") @Valid ATO aSearchForm,
        @SessionAttribute(Constants.USERSESSION) UserAccountTO userAccountTO,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
      // business logic
 }
```

However, I am not sure why when my button on click, it does not trigger the API, instead, it redirected me to page not found. It doesn't even execute the API as I put some dummy logger in there but it does not get printed out. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `@ModelAttribute("TO")` to `@ModelAttribute("aTO")` in second handler.